# get length of sequences

Tags: r, sequence, run-length-encoding

I a have a column of data (45,000 rows!) which represents when a filter is running or turned off (depends on conditions, shown as a zero). the log file records as follows (actually 2 columns the first being the count since start)

```
col 1: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10.....45,000)
col 2: 1,2,3,4,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,0,0,0,0,0 etc.
```

What I want is 2 columns ("time on" and "time off") with above data this would be:

```
"time on" 4,0,12,0,3
```

(i.e. the lengths in order of the non-zero sequences) and a corresponding

```
"time off" 0,4,0,8,5
```

(the lengths of the number of zero's in order).

Ultimately I am wanting to produce a bar graph showing days on, days off over time

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with `rle` ("run-length encoding"):

```
x = c(1,2,3,4,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,0,0,
      0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,0,0,0,0,0)
runs = rle(x != 0)
nonzero = runs$lengths
nonzero[! runs$values] = 0
nonzero
# Output:
# [1]  4  0 12  0  3  0
zeros = runs$lengths
zeros[runs$values] = 0
zeros
# Output:
# [1] 0 4 0 8 0 5
```

Comment: That works for me not used rle much, good learning. How could one then plot on the same graph both "zero" and "nonzero"? I was thinking overlaid bar plots in ggplot2 but was trying more for the equivalent of a horizontal tornado graph but not sure how to approach it.

Comment: @ramonskovitch: Probably best to ask a separate question about generating the plot.